# I want to read HTML elements on a site and post them to a PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

i've created a website where i can drag and drop paragraphs between two div elements

one named "mods" and one name "modlist"

Id like it so that when i press a button "publish List" i can read through all the elements inside the Mods List div, then Post them to a PHP script so that i can save them into an SQL database.

Ive tried solving this for a while now, what im currently trying is when i press the publish list button, a confirmation popup thingy shows to the user:

```
<form>
    <p>Are you sure?</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Yep" onclick="return modListUpdate('{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}')">
</form>
```

And that will go into:

```
function modListUpdate(path) {
    var ancestor = document.getElementById("modList"),
        descendents = ancestor.getElementsByTagName('*');

    var i, e, modID;
    var form = document.createElement("form");

    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    var source = document.createElement("input");
    source.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    source.setAttribute("name", "source");
    source.setAttribute("value", "newModList");
    form.appendChild(source);

    for (i = 0; i < descendents.length; i++) {
        e = descendents[i];
        modID = e.id;
        modID = modID.substr(3);
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "mod"+modID);
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", modID);

        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

And then i got a php script ready to pick up the POST, but it dosent seem to work...
Any ideas why? or maybe a better way to solve this?

Comment: no action and method set on the form.... try using AJAX call to accomplish this ;)

Comment: That's because the form in the javascript is supposed to do the post action